# Does AWS API Gateway private integration with ALB works with ALB https listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a public API gateway with HTTP API I'm trying to forward traffic to an internal ALB with private link. It works well for an HTTP listener but I can't make it work with an HTTPS listener. Is that possible ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To create a private integration, you must first create a VPC link. Check this [link for creating VPC links](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vpc-links.html)

After you’ve created a VPC link, you can set up private integrations that connect to an Application Load Balancer via Network Load Balancer.

So the flow would be like APIgateway -> VPC link -> NLB -> ALB -> target groups

By default, private integration traffic uses the HTTP protocol. You can specify a [tlsConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigatewayv2/latest/api-reference/apis-apiid-integrations-integrationid.html) if you require private integration traffic to use HTTPS.